# What is the distinction between gaudium and laetitia when both denote "joy"?

Tags: vocabulary, meaning, word-comparison

Both *gaudium* and *laetitia* denote joy, but appear to be used differently depending on the circumstances. What is the distinction between the two (or more) Latin words for joy?

Answer (score 14):

*Laetitia* is a state of being, from *laetus* *happy*. Someone who is *laetus* has *gaudium*, in the sense that someone who is rich has money. It more generally should be translated as *happiness* instead of *joy*.

It should be noted that the two words became synonymous in poetry and in later Latin prose.

See the Lewis and Short entries under [gaudium](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0060%3Aalphabetic+letter%3Dg%3Aentry+group%3D1%3Aentry%3Dgaudium) and [laetitia](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0060%3Aalphabetic+letter%3Dl%3Aentry+group%3D2%3Aentry%3Dlaetitia).

There's also [*hilaritas*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0060%3Aalphabetic+letter%3Dh%3Aentry+group%3D4%3Aentry%3Dhilaritas), which is more similar to *laetitia* than *gaudium*, and means general *cheerfulness*. Think of it as the beaming smile on customer service's face rather than the joy at finding a sale (*gaudium*) or the happiness from having a series of successful encounters at a store (*laetitia*).

Comment: Good answer: for those interested in Thomistic usage,  *beatitudo* = "happiness" (Aristotelian sense), *gaudium* = "joy" (passion of the soul), and *laetitia* is seen as equivalent to *gaudium*, but is mostly used with reference to older texts like those of Augustine.

Comment: I would suggest that the emotional state accompanying the beaming smile on customer service's face is almost certainly not *hilaritas*.

Answer (score 10):

One of the differences is the way of expressing joy.
This is not the only difference, but let me focus on this aspect.
The aspect of expressing joy is not always present, but my understanding is that these words have such tone.

- [*Gaudium*](http://latinlexicon.org/definition.php?p1=1006709) is inward joy that you keep to yourself.
  It is about feeling something inside, not about showing it.
- [*Exsultatio*](http://latinlexicon.org/definition.php?p1=1005921) is more like jumping around in joy.
  It emphasizes showing the joy to everyone — which to me at least includes a mild connotation of a shallower feeling.
- [*Laetitia*](http://latinlexicon.org/definition.php?p1=1008998) is somewhere between these two.

These words can express a difference in the way of expressing joy, but this aspect is not the only one and may well be entirely absent in some cases.
As Alex B. commented, Hermann Menge (Menge 2011, Lateinische Synonymik) says basically this.
Sometimes the words are used indiscriminately to mean "joy", and sometimes rhythmic considerations lead to preferring one word over its near synonyms.

Comment: Though see @C.M. Weimer's point about *gaudium* and *laetitia* becoming synonymous in later Latin prose.

Comment: Given your explanation for *exsultātiō*, note the connection *saltō* > *saltātiō*. The short vowel of *saltō* became *sult-* (fronting and backing of short, unstressed vowels being commonplace). Using the frequentative (form meaning repeated action) of *saliō* means that *exsultātiō* quite literally means to be ‘jumping from’, I would assume hence ‘around’, presumably in joy.