# What does 'fac et gaudium' mean?

Tags: latin-to-english-translation

What does '*fac et gaudium*' mean? Or is it just a fragment? Found in old notebook. I know it's something to do with taking action and then delight, but the sense is unclear to me.

Comment: Is it possible that it is, or is meant to be, fac ut gaudeam, 'Make me glad'?

Comment: (Follow up: In *Latin for all occasions*, Henry Beard also used *fac ut gaudeam* to render the line 'Make my day' from the Clint Eastwood film *Sudden impact*.)

Comment: Yes, you're spot on!  I remembered that I had that tome on my bookshelf & must have mistranscribed it into said notebook.

Comment: Could it be 'Make my day' as in taunt. prefaced maybe by 'age' - 'Go ahead'?

Comment: @cnread Can you post that as an answer, even a short one? It appears to be the correct one.

Answer (score 4):

(Converting two old comments into a new answer, as requested)

It appears that *et* is a typo, and the phrase should be *fac ut gaudeam* – literally, 'Make me glad.'

In the book *Latin for all occasions*, Henry Beard uses *fac ut gaudeam* to render the line 'Make my day' from the Clint Eastwood film *Sudden impact* (p 56, under the heading 'Timeless lines from the movies').

Answer (score 2):

I would translate it as "and make joy" or perhaps "make joy, too".
This does not feel like fully idiomatic Latin to me, but the sense seems to be: "remember to enjoy among other things".

The imperative *fac* (which sounds remarkably much like the English swear word) means "make" or "do".

The word *et* is often translated as "and", but it can mean many kinds of addition.
Perhaps "too" or "also" would fit better here.
Without further context — which presumably does not exist in a throwaway remark in an old notebook — is is hard to judge.
In my more verbose translation I translated *et* as "among other things".

There are many words for different kinds of joy, and *gaudium* is one of them.
[Here is an older question comparing some of the Latin joy words.](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/696/79)

A far more idiomatic way to say "enjoy!" would be *gaude!* instead of *fac gaudium!*.
I guess this construction is a calque of the writer's primary language, possibly Italian with its ubiquitous *fare*.