# Translating “Claim Joy” as a Personal Motto

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, vocabulary, motto, word-choice, imperative

I’m trying to come up with a good translation for my own personal motto, “Claim Joy.” I use it in the context of my own mental health struggles and a reminder that you can’t wait for happiness, you have to go out and find it.

Grammatically, I’d like the verb to be indicative, but also poetic. The precise word I’m looking for seems elusive. As for “joy,” I’m struggling to decide between *gaudium* and *laetitia*. I think *laetitia* is the correct word as it feels more akin to the idea of inward and outward joy. The feeling of being inwardly happy and expressing it outwardly.

Thanks for the help. It’s been a looong time since my senior year of high school Latin.

Comment: You might find [this question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/696/what-is-the-distinction-between-gaudium-and-laetitia-when-both-denote-joy) useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll start with *laetitiam repete!* 'Reclaim joy!'. I don't see much difference between *laetitia* and *gaudium*. I hope others can elaborate.

Answer (score 7):

My mind immediately went to *carpe* ['seize, claim, enjoy, pluck'](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/carpo#Latin) for the verb: as well as connotations of plucking something off a tree, which seems in line with what you want, it also echoes the well-known *carpe diem* 'seize the day' which is both poetic and means it will be more readily understood.

Picking *gaudium* for 'joy' lets you continue the echo, and I think will also be more readily understood by literate non-Latinists than *laetitia* (which has the disadvantage of resembling a name, and you don't want to give the impression you're claiming a woman!).

Comment: I think *carpe!* would fit nicely here.

Answer (score 4):

Just saw that an answer has been accepted.
Yet it may be interesting to consider using a *gerundivum* here, in pretty much the same way as Horatius' **Nunc est bibendum**.

If we take "Claim joy" to mean "Joy must be claimed", and translate "claim" by **vindicare** we can say

**Laetitia vindicanda est**

or

**Gaudium vindicandum est**.

You can leave out **est** to make it a little stronger.

Comment: I like this one, too.